Why is it so slowly while transferring files from windows through WinRM by using python?
I'm using python + winrm to get files from a windows server. The code runs fine but slowly. It can only get about 10GB per day by this way.
If I copy files through remote desktop(mstsc.exe or Other remote clients) manually, I can get a file of 140GB just at one night.
I want to know why my code runs so slowly like that, and how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.
Here is the environment:
python 3.7.9
pywinrm 0.4.3

WinRm configration:
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30

My code:
import winrm
import re
import base64
import os
import logging
from winrm import Response

logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logging.getLogger('spnego').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
log = logging.getLogger('')

class WinRmConnection:
    def __init__(self, hostname='', username='', password='',
                 connect_now=True, **kwargs):
        self.__rdc = None
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.transport = kwargs.get('transport', 'ntlm')
        self.port = kwargs.get('port', 5985)

        if connect_now:
            self.connect(hostname=f'{hostname}:{self.port}', username=username, password=password, transport=self.transport)

    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        hostname = kwargs.get('hostname', self.hostname)
        username = kwargs.get('username', self.username)
        password = kwargs.get('password', self.password)
        transport = kwargs.get('transport', self.transport)
        try:
            assert hostname
            password = password
        except:
            raise Exception('Connection params error.')
        self.__rdc = winrm.Session(
            hostname,
            auth=(username, password),
            transport=transport
        )

    def close(self):
        try:
            self.__rdc.close()
        except:
            pass

    def cmd(self, cmd, ps=False, raise_err=False, retry=3):
        if not cmd:
            return ''
        log.debug('Execute %scommand: %s' % ('' if not ps else 'PowerShell ', cmd))

        try:
            result = self.__rdc.run_ps(cmd) if ps else self.__rdc.run_cmd(cmd)
            stdout = result.std_out
            stderr = result.std_err
            try:
                out = stdout.decode('utf-8')
                err = stderr.decode('utf-8')
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                out = stdout.decode('gbk')
                err = stderr.decode('gbk')
            if raise_err and (stderr and err):
                raise Exception(err)
            if result.status_code:
                out = err
        except Exception as e:
            log.exception('Error occurred when executing [%s]: %s' % (cmd, repr(e)))
            if raise_err:
                raise e
            return ''
        else:
            log.debug('Command output: %s' % out)
            reg = re.compile(r'^\*')
            return reg.sub('', out.strip())

    def download(self, remote_path, local_path, overwrite=True):
        is_dir_src = 0
        remote_path = remote_path.rstrip(' \t\\/')
        if self.cmd(f'Test-Path {remote_path} -PathType Container', ps=True) == 'True':
            is_dir_src = 1
        log.debug(f'Prepare to download ' + ('directory ' if is_dir_src else '') + f'{remote_path} from server.')

        target = ''
        append_name = remote_path.split('\\')[-1]
        if is_dir_src:  # downloading folder
            local_path = os.path.join(local_path, append_name)
            if not os.path.exists(local_path):
                os.makedirs(local_path)
            elif not overwrite:
                raise Exception('Destination path has been exists already.')
            target += local_path
        else:  # downloading file
            if not os.path.exists(local_path):  # treat `local_path` as a folder if it does not exists
                os.makedirs(local_path)
                target += os.path.join(local_path, append_name)
            elif not overwrite:
                raise Exception('Destination path has been exists already.')
            elif os.path.isdir(local_path):
                target += os.path.join(local_path, append_name)
            else:
                target += local_path

        result = 1
        if not is_dir_src:
            result = int(self._do_get_file(remote_path, target))
            if not result:
                log.debug(f'Failed while downloading {remote_path}.')
        else:
            obj = self.cmd(f'Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath {remote_path} -Name', ps=True)
            if obj:
                for o in obj.splitlines():
                    result &= bool(self.download(f'{remote_path}\\{o}', target))

        log.debug(f'Finish downloading {remote_path} to {target}.')
        return target if result else None

    def _do_get_file(self, remote_path, local_path, buffer_size=2 ** 19):
        # Refer to: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py
        # 0.5MB chunks by default
        out_file = None
        err = 0
        try:
            offset = 0
            while True:
                command_id = None
                try:
                    script = '''
                        $path = '%(path)s'
                        $buffer_size = %(buffer_size)d
                        $offset = %(offset)d

                        $stream = New-Object -TypeName IO.FileStream($path, [IO.FileMode]::Open, [IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
                        $stream.Seek($offset, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) > $null
                        $buffer = New-Object -TypeName byte[] $buffer_size
                        $bytes_read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer_size)
                        if ($bytes_read -gt 0) {
                            $bytes = $buffer[0..($bytes_read - 1)]
                            [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
                        }
                        $stream.Close() > $null
                    ''' % dict(buffer_size=buffer_size, path=remote_path, offset=offset)
                    script = '\n'.join([x.strip() for x in script.splitlines() if x.strip()])
                    encoded_ps = base64.b64encode(script.encode('utf_16_le')).decode('utf-8')
                    shell_id = self.__rdc.protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)
                    data = None
                    try:
                        command_id = self.__rdc.protocol.run_command(shell_id, 'PowerShell', ('-EncodedCommand', encoded_ps))
                        resptuple = self.__rdc.protocol.get_command_output(shell_id, command_id)
                        result = Response(tuple(v.decode('utf-8', 'replace') if isinstance(v, bytes) else v for v in resptuple))
                        if result.status_code != 0:
                            raise Exception(result.std_err)
                        data = base64.b64decode(result.std_out.strip())
                        self.__rdc.protocol.cleanup_command(shell_id, command_id)
                        self.__rdc.protocol.close_shell(shell_id)
                    except Exception as e:
                        log.exception(e)
                        log.error(f'Error occurred when downloading to `{local_path}`.')
                        err = 1
                        if command_id:
                            self.__rdc.protocol.cleanup_command(shell_id, command_id)
                        self.__rdc.protocol.close_shell(shell_id)
                    else:
                        if data is None:
                            break
                        else:
                            if not out_file:
                                out_file = open(local_path, 'wb')
                            out_file.write(data)
                            if len(data) < buffer_size:
                                break
                            offset += len(data)
                            log.debug('%d bytes done.' % offset)

                except Exception as e:
                    log.exception(e)
                    log.error(f'Error occurred when downloading to `{local_path}`.')
                    err = 1
                    if command_id:
                        try:
                            self.__rdc.protocol.cleanup_command(shell_id, command_id)
                        except:
                            pass
                    self.__rdc.protocol.close_shell(shell_id)
                    break
        finally:
            if out_file:
                out_file.close()
            return not err

Run:
    params = {
        'hostname': '',  # remote IP address
        'username': '',  # username of remote server to login
        'password': ''  # password of remote server to login
    }
    remote = WinRmConnection(**params)
    remote.download(r'e:\temp\1.txt', r'd:\work')
    remote.close()


(1) increase your buffer size: maybe 1 MB or bigger. (2) try to use binary mode, use base64 encode and decode will make data big then original data about 1/3. (3) just open close session 1 file one time, do not open close session many times, not every data block.

(4) try to Parallel operation many sub directory to one zip file. (a) Transferring many small files, and (b) packaging many small files into an uncompressed zip file, the speed of transferring one file will be faster than the speed of transferring many small files. (5) Turn the task of transferring a single file into another process and try to transfer multiple files in parallel at the same time.

about (1) . do not use base64 to encode/decode file to text, just use binary mode.

use winrm to invoke other process to transferring file.  Invoke-WebRequest or BitsTransfer. or curl upload remove file to your pc web. or your pc provide FTP, you can send command to remote server , use ftp u[load file to your pc.

or use xcopy , in remote server run xcopy , copy file to your pc.

@life888888 Thank you. Very much appreciated. First I will try to re-coding the part of file-transfer and test on your advice :)
